# change a python script to Unix line-ending convention

Tags: python, unix, hadoop

What is the easiest way to change a python script to `Unix` line-ending convention?

I am running a python script on `Hadoop` and seeing the following `stderr` log:

```
/usr/bin/env: python
: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Many code editors have this feature, or you can use the `dos2unix` command line utility. You can also configure git to convert on commit, or use Unix-style everywhere.

Comment: @MattDMo you are right. I just used SciTE editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting from a friend's response:
First you should download `SciTE` (you can download other text editors as well).
In `SciTE`, you'd first enable End of Line from the view menu to see the line endings then under the Options menu, adjust Line End Characters and then (again under Options) Convert Line End Characters. You should choose the `LF` option.